# is it possible to download apache 2.4 mod_proxy_http2.so file for redhat 6?

Tags: apache-2.4

Is it possible to get the compiled version of mod_proxy_http2.so for Apache 2.4 instead of recompiling apache?
I am having issues with compiling apache right now and need this module asap.

Comment: technically this is possible. You need someone who builds a package for you though.
Are you using the http24 packages from the software collection?

Comment: You can get it from the same place you got your compiled Apache.